# how to prepare Prometheus Client Library for Modern C++ for using in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, prometheus

I want to use [prometheus-cpp](https://github.com/jupp0r/prometheus-cpp) library to get metrics from my application.

I use [prometheus-cpp](https://github.com/jupp0r/prometheus-cpp/archive/refs/heads/master.zip)
[CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/jupp0r/prometheus-cpp/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt)
CMake v3.21.1.0
Visual Studio 2019.

But I don't understand how to prepare the **prometheus-cpp** for using in Visual Studio 2019.
When I do CMake instructions from the **prometheus-cpp** webpage, I get some errors in console output.

For example, when I do the CMake build [instructions](https://github.com/jupp0r/prometheus-cpp#via-cmake) **cmake --install**, I get the :

```
cmake.exe --install .
-- Install configuration: "Release"
CMake Error at core/cmake_install.cmake:56 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "G:/prometheus-cpp/_build/bin/Release/prometheus-cpp-core.dll":
  No error.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake_install.cmake:42 (include)
```

But there is no a **Release** folder in my 
G:/prometheus-cpp/_build/bin/ 
There is only **Debug** folder here!

As @vre advised, I called the build command twice from the build directory: **cmake --build . --config Release --parallel 4** and **cmake --build . --config Debug --parallel 4**

Afet that there are both Release and Debug folders appeared.
I called **cmake.exe --install .** , added the path to **c:\Program Files (x86)\prometheus-cpp\include** to
**AdditionalIncludeDirectories** in Visual Studio and started the project with this [code](https://github.com/jupp0r/prometheus-cpp#usage) as Debug x64.
Here is the output:

```
1>prometheus_test.obj : error LNK2019: reference to unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl prometheus::Counter::Counter(void)" (__imp_??0Counter@prometheus@@QEAA@XZ) in function "class std::unique_ptr<class prometheus::Counter,struct std::default_delete<class prometheus::Counter> > __cdecl prometheus::detail::make_unique<class prometheus::Counter>(void)" (??$make_unique@VCounter@prometheus@@$$V@detail@prometheus@@YA?AV?$unique_ptr@VCounter@prometheus@@U?$default_delete@VCounter@prometheus@@@std@@@std@@XZ).
1>prometheus_test.obj : error LNK2019: reference to unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl prometheus::Counter::Increment(void)" (__imp_?Increment@Counter@prometheus@@QEAAXXZ) in function main.
1>prometheus_test.obj : error LNK2019: reference to unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class prometheus::detail::Builder<class prometheus::Counter> __cdecl prometheus::BuildCounter(void)" (__imp_?BuildCounter@prometheus@@YA?AV?$Builder@VCounter@prometheus@@@detail@1@XZ) in function main.
1>prometheus_test.obj : error LNK2019: reference to unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl prometheus::Exposer::Exposer(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned __int64,struct CivetCallbacks const *)" (__imp_??0Exposer@prometheus@@QEAA@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@_KPEBUCivetCallbacks@@@Z) in function main.
1>prometheus_test.obj : error LNK2019: reference to unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl prometheus::Exposer::~Exposer(void)" (__imp_??1Exposer@prometheus@@QEAA@XZ) в функции main.
1>prometheus_test.obj : error LNK2019: reference to unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl prometheus::Exposer::RegisterCollectable(class std::weak_ptr<class prometheus::Collectable> const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_?RegisterCollectable@Exposer@prometheus@@QEAAXAEBV?$weak_ptr@VCollectable@prometheus@@@std@@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@4@@Z) in function main.
1>prometheus_test.obj : error LNK2019: reference to unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl prometheus::Registry::Registry(enum prometheus::Registry::InsertBehavior)" (__imp_??0Registry@prometheus@@QEAA@W4InsertBehavior@01@@Z) in function "void __cdecl std::_Construct_in_place<class prometheus::Registry>(class prometheus::Registry &)" (??$_Construct_in_place@VRegistry@prometheus@@$$V@std@@YAXAEAVRegistry@prometheus@@@Z).
1>prometheus_test.obj : error LNK2019: reference to unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl prometheus::Registry::~Registry(void)" (__imp_??1Registry@prometheus@@UEAA@XZ) в функции "public: virtual void * __cdecl prometheus::Registry::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GRegistry@prometheus@@UEAAPEAXI@Z).
1>prometheus_test.obj : error LNK2019: reference to unresolved external symbol "public: class prometheus::detail::Builder<class prometheus::Counter> & __cdecl prometheus::detail::Builder<class prometheus::Counter>::Name(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?Name@?$Builder@VCounter@prometheus@@@detail@prometheus@@QEAAAEAV123@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) in function main.
1>prometheus_test.obj : error LNK2019: reference to unresolved external symbol "public: class prometheus::detail::Builder<class prometheus::Counter> & __cdecl prometheus::detail::Builder<class prometheus::Counter>::Help(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?Help@?$Builder@VCounter@prometheus@@@detail@prometheus@@QEAAAEAV123@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) in function main.
1>prometheus_test.obj : error LNK2019: reference to unresolved external symbol "public: class prometheus::Family<class prometheus::Counter> & __cdecl prometheus::detail::Builder<class prometheus::Counter>::Register(class prometheus::Registry &)" (?Register@?$Builder@VCounter@prometheus@@@detail@prometheus@@QEAAAEAV?$Family@VCounter@prometheus@@@3@AEAVRegistry@3@@Z) in function main.
1>prometheus_test.obj : error LNK2019: reference to unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) private: class prometheus::Counter & __cdecl prometheus::Family<class prometheus::Counter>::Add(class std::map<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct std::less<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const ,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > > const &,class std::unique_ptr<class prometheus::Counter,struct std::default_delete<class prometheus::Counter> >)" (__imp_?Add@?$Family@VCounter@prometheus@@@prometheus@@AEAAAEAVCounter@2@AEBV?$map@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@U?$less@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@@std@@@2@@std@@V?$unique_ptr@VCounter@prometheus@@U?$default_delete@VCounter@prometheus@@@std@@@5@@Z) in function "public: class prometheus::Counter & __cdecl prometheus::Family<class prometheus::Counter>::Add<>(class std::map<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct std::less<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const ,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > > const &)" (??$Add@$$V@?$Family@VCounter@prometheus@@@prometheus@@QEAAAEAVCounter@1@AEBV?$map@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@U?$less@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@@std@@@2@@std@@@Z).
1>prometheus_test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class std::vector<struct prometheus::MetricFamily,class std::allocator<struct prometheus::MetricFamily> > __cdecl prometheus::Registry::Collect(void)const " (?Collect@Registry@prometheus@@UEBA?AV?$vector@UMetricFamily@prometheus@@V?$allocator@UMetricFamily@prometheus@@@std@@@std@@XZ).
1>G:\_Job\_Education\Cpp\Prometheus\prometheus_test\x64\Debug\prometheus_test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: unresolved external symbols: 13
```

Could you explaine me please, how to prepare the **prometheus-cpp** correctly by CMake to use in Visual Studio 2019??

Comment: Please note, that on Stack Overflow we don't write *guides* and *tutorials*. Here we answer on questions about specific problems. We could help with the problem you have faced, but for that you need to show **exact error message** you have faced and exact steps you have performed.

Comment: You have the [build instructions](https://github.com/jupp0r/prometheus-cpp#via-cmake) and the [consumer instructions](https://github.com/jupp0r/prometheus-cpp#cmake) mentioned on the github site. They also mention a consuming example in the second link. You may need to explicitely add the generator (`-G "Visual Studio 16 2019"`) to the build command. Otherwise, please show the console output of CMake to give further advice.

Comment: @vre, I have added the console output of CMake. What can you advice for me?

Comment: To build both configurations with MSVC Compiler you need to call the build command twice from the build directory: `cmake --build . --config Release --parallel 4` and `cmake --build . --config Debug --parallel 4`

Comment: @vre, Ok , I have done it. After that I use cmake --install . and in my c:\Program Files (x86)\prometheus-cpp\ appears 3 folders: bin, include and lib.

Comment: @vre, When I try to start the code example from the prometheus webpage in Visual Studio I get an error: reference to unresolved external symbol "__declspec (dllimport) public : __cdecl prometheus::Exposer::Exposer(class std ........... in main function

Comment: Please add all necessary information, the consuming code, the CMakeLists.txt and the error output when consuming prometheus-cpp to your question.

Comment: @vre Ok, I have added.

Comment: Are both prometheus-cpp configurations, Release and Debug installed? You may also need to run the install twice, `cmake --install . --config Release` and  `cmake --install . --config Debug`. What happens if you switch your example to Release x64?

Comment: It seems like you are not linking prometheus-cpp to your example, that means you are  missing the `target_link_libraries` command in your `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: @vre, this file is not mine. Its from the author of the prometheus-cpp code. About missing the target_link_libraries command - what shoul I write to CMakeLists.txt file?

Comment: Something equivalent to what is linked on the Github Readme in the Consuming section. This [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/jupp0r/prometheus-cpp/blob/master/cmake/project-import-cmake/CMakeLists.txt) shows exactly what to do.

Comment: @vre, I don't understand your very cryptic clue. What exactly should I write to the file?

Comment: Simply `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12 FATAL_ERROR)
project(prometheus-cpp-import)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
find_package(prometheus-cpp CONFIG REQUIRED)
add_executable(sample-server sample_server.cc)
target_link_libraries(sample-server PRIVATE prometheus-cpp::pull)
`. You may need to add `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\prometheus-cpp"` to your cmake command to build the above CMakeLists.txt